# my sql query to find sort two columns independently

Tags: mysql, sql

there is a table having two columns say id and name , i want both columns to be sorted.

```
table :
id name
3 y
2 z
1 x

output should be
id name
1 x
2 y
3 z
```

can anybody do it in single sql query ???

Comment: This is weird, the name `y` does not belong to the id `2` and you want to have this after sorting. This is not called sorting rather updating the record.

Comment: well, the record doesn't have to be updated. it just has to be temporarily broken. it's definitely weird tho.

Answer (score 1):

You need need to do weird stuff. because what you want to do is weird.

```
select b1.id, b2.name from
(
  select @row := @row +1 as row, id
    from broken, (select @row := 0) rr
  order by id asc
) b1
inner join
(
  select @row2 := @row2 + 1 as row, name
    from broken, (select @row2 := 0) rr
  order by name asc
) b2
on b1.row = b2.row
```

demo fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d47c/7

Comment: Yup weird, nicely put! (+1) ^^

Comment: i almost feel that this was a thought exercise more than anything that someone would actually need to do

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *
, row_number() over (order by ID) as IDRow
, row_number() over (order by name) as NameRow
into #temp
from table

select a.ID, b.Name from #temp a
full outer join #temp b
on a.IDRow = b.NameRow
order by IDRow, NameRow
```

If you wanted, you could do this with subqueries instead of the temp table, but it'll probably be faster this way.